# Upper and lower of a passed value in a scala Array

Tags: arrays, scala, arraylist, seq

I have the below sorted Array with me -

```
scala> Array(10,20,30,40,50)
res15: Array[Int] = Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

How can I get the lower and upper bound from this if I pass a value ?

Ex- if i pass 11 , I should return 10 and 20.
If I pass 25, I should be able to get 20 and 30.
If I pass 10, I should be able to get 10 and 20.
If I pass 50, I should be able to get 40 and 50.

Comment: What should happen if I pass `-1` what should happen if I pass `100`? It is always guaranteed that the array is sorted? Do it has to be an **Array**, or can we change it for any real collection?

Comment: @Luis.  Thanks for your reply. Sorry for the incomplete info ! The array is a sorted one.I have edited the question. Lets rule out the case where in we pass the value beyond the extremes(like -1 or 100).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array is sorted and I understand the question correctly, I would just search for the first number that is higher then the number provided and that is your upper bound, lower bound is that index minus one

```scala
val arr = Array(10,20,30,40,50)
val numToFind = 11 // or 25
val upperBoundIndex = arr.indexWhere( _ >= numToFind )
val lowerBoundIndex = upperBoundIndex - 1
val upperBound = arr(upperBoundIndex)
val lowerBound = arr(lowerBoundIndex)
```

EDIT1: Without provided edge cases I do not know what you want to do in case it over or underflows. But something likes this will work.

```scala
val arr = Array(10,20,30,40,50)
val numToFind = 11 // or 25
val upperBoundIndex = arr.indexWhere( _ >= numToFind 

if (upperBoundIndex == 0) {
  // Upper bound is first so there is no lower bound
} else if (upperBoundIndex == -1) {
  // the lower bound is probably your arr.last
} else { 
  val lowerBoundIndex = upperBoundIndex - 1
  val upperBound = arr(upperBoundIndex)
  val lowerBound = arr(lowerBoundIndex)
}
```

EDIT2: Switched `>` for `>=`. To ignore edge cases use the first solution.

Comment: @abc_spark You do not provide your edge usecases but I made an edit and you can only fill in for the comments

Comment: sorry for the incompltee info. I have edited the question.